# Magento2 display all coupon codes in custom module phtml

Tags: magento2

I have to display list of all coupon codes in a phtml of custom module. Anyone can explain me the process of displaying all coupon list. I have created a custom module which is displaying hello word at frontend using module creater. what will be next step to do ?

Comment: Do you need only the coupon code list or anything else with coupon list?

Comment: I have to display a table which will list all coupon codes with columns Coupon(captcha image of coupon code) , Description, Minimum, Quantity, Cumulative, Date, Action(column will have a button copy for coping text) at frontend website